# C++ - How to correctly bind a default_random_engine to two different uniform_int_distributions

Tags: c++, stdbind

I am trying to use two different objects of `std::uniform_int_distribution` bound (using `std::bind`) with the same object `std::default_random_engine` as argument (as described here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/), but binding them together results in different behavior than using them unbound:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    default_random_engine generator;

    int dist1Max = 10, dist2Max = 10;

    uniform_int_distribution<int> dist1(1, dist1Max);
    uniform_int_distribution<int> dist2(1, dist2Max);

    function<int()> boundDist1 = std::bind(dist1, generator);
    function<int()> boundDist2 = std::bind(dist2, generator);

    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
    {
        cout << boundDist1() << " " << boundDist2() << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
    {
        cout << dist1(generator) << " " << dist2(generator) << endl;
    }
}
```

The second loop produces random numbers as I want them, while in the first one `boundDist1()` and `boundDist2()` always produce the same number in each cycle of the loop.

So my question is:
How does `std::bind` change the behavior of the function call and how can I avoid this problem?

Comment: _'How does std::bind change the behavior of the function call'_ Usually it doesn't?!?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It seems to do in this case, because the use of the bound object boundDist1 does not seem to advance the state of the default_random_engine in boundDist2, although I bound the same default_random_engine to it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, see [this ideone run](http://ideone.com/XjhQcW). It *does* change something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that by default, `bind` will copy its argument to the closure, rather than create a reference to them. Random engines being copyable, you get two distinct engines that create the same numbers.

You need to wrap the generators in `bind` with [`std::ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref). This tells `bind` that you want to keep a reference to the engine, not make a copy of it.

```
function<int()> boundDist1 = std::bind(dist1, std::ref(generator));
function<int()> boundDist2 = std::bind(dist2, std::ref(generator));
```

Here's an [ideone run with it](http://ideone.com/iicJsZ).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, now it works as intended.